# How to Merge One Pandas Dataframe with Another on the Union of the Indices, Specifying a Preference for Data from One where there is an Overlap?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes.  Some indices overlap.  I want to produce a union of the two dataframes, such that the resulting dataframe is indexed on the union index of the two dataframes (every index in both dataframes appears in the the resulting dataframe once).  In the instance where the indices overlap, I want to specify which dataframe to insert the data from.

Here is an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit':['Apple','Orange','Banana','Pear'],'State':['Ripe','Not Ripe','Ripe','Ripe']},index=['A','B','C','E'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit':['Orange','Banana','Apple','Orange'],'State':['Not Ripe','Ripe','Ripe','Ripe']},index=['B','D','E','F'])

df1 >>>

    Fruit   State
A   Apple   Ripe
B   Orange  Not Ripe
C   Banana  Ripe
E   Pear    Ripe

df2 >>>

    Fruit   State
B   Orange  Not Ripe
D   Banana  Ripe
E   Apple   Ripe
F   Orange  Ripe
```

So the combined index would be A, B, C, D, E and F.  I want to ensure that where the index is unique to one dataframe, it appears in the resulting dataframe.  If the index appears in both dataframes, then I want to ensure that the data from df2 appears in the dataframe.

The resulting dataframe would be:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit':['Apple','Orange','Banana','Banana','Apple','Orange'],'State':['Ripe','Not Ripe','Ripe','Ripe','Ripe','Ripe']},index=['A','B','C','D','E','F'])

df3 >>>

    Fruit   State
A   Apple   Ripe
B   Orange  Not Ripe
C   Banana  Ripe
D   Banana  Ripe
E   Apple   Ripe
F   Orange  Ripe
```

I have looked at merge, join and concat functions.  I have a feeling that the merge function is going to be the one, but am having difficulty figuring out the correct parameterisation here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html), which is the function designed to do exactly what you want:

```
df2.combine_first(df1)
```

output:

```
    Fruit     State
A   Apple      Ripe
B  Orange  Not Ripe
C  Banana      Ripe
D  Banana      Ripe
E   Apple      Ripe
F  Orange      Ripe
```